# array- having some issues

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find the Smallest Integer Not in a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586858/find-the-smallest-integer-not-in-a-list)

An interview question.
given a unsorted int array. How to find first int that bigger than 0 and not appears in that given array.
for example:

```
input :[1,2,0]   
output: 3

input [2,4,-1,1]  
output: ３
```

I gave two solution

```
a) sort.  Time C is: O(n), space C is O(1)  
b) bitmap. Time Complexity :O(n), space O(n)
```

But interviewer doesn't satisfied. he said there is Time O(n)
and constant space solution.

Any thought?

The resource is from my online friend.

Comment: input [2,4,-1,1] output: 2. Are you sure the answer is 2 and not 3?

Comment: 1. Are you sure, input [2,4,-1,1] yields output 2? Shouldn't it be 3? 2. Good sorting algorithms are O(n*log(n)), not O(n). 3. O(1) is constant space.

Comment: Is the answer to the 2nd example correct - should it be 3?