# How to find the smallest missing positive integer from an unsorted stream of positive integers?

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find the Smallest Integer Not in a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586858/find-the-smallest-integer-not-in-a-list)

you have a stream of unsorted positive integers. After you read all the numbers from the stream you have to determine the smallest positive integer that is missing from the stream.

**example:**
Stream of positive integers: 6 7 8 9 1 2

ans : 3

Stream of positive integers: 1 2 3 4 5

and : 6

Stream of positive integers: 12 87 899

ans : 1

I wanted to solve the problem without taking any extra data structure. Is it possible?

I am stuck on this problem. Did all the research i could on the internet, but, no luck.
Could anyone help.

Comment: How are you reading the numbers from the stream?

Comment: @Jordan Kaye: does it matter? it's a stream..

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Well, there's the possibility that the numbers are only available after the entire stream has been read, or that they are available individually; this would impact possible solutions.

Comment: @Jordan Kaye: for me, stream means you cannot do random access. but let's see what the OP says.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Which was the purpose of my question - just to clarify :)

Comment: @JordanKaye It's a stream that means they are available individually.

Comment: @Oren - Not really a duplicate if truly needing to be done on a stream basis. Without storing and sorting, this is an impossible problem to solve, as there may be arbitrarily multiple states (areas / gaps on the number line) able to be jumped to from a current state. As #'s come in and there is separation between it and all other numbers, it creates another state. If a # comes in that fills in a state (gap in the # line) yes you will move to exactly the next gap, but where is that if you havent' been keeping track of all potential gaps along the way.

Comment: @trumpetlicks: Since storing is required as you say, this *is* a duplicate.

Comment: @interjay - LOL, suppose you're right :-) Unless of course I am incorrect and there is a way to do it on a stream basis.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the array as you read it using insertion sort (seeing as how the data comes from a stream, this should be efficient) and then iterate through it. If `1` is missing, that's your answer. If it's there, you can iteratively check if the next integer is the next number in the array, otherwise the next integer is the missing one.

Comment: i dont have an array. Its a stream of numbers that is coming one by one. Now i could create an array while reading and then sort it. But its not that efficient.

Comment: @xtrmcode au contraire... If you use insertion sort, it should be actually really fast. This is even more efficient considering you have to read the whole stream until you can report the missing number.

Comment: at the moment I don't see a more efficient solution. perhaps a bitmap, but only if the range of numbers is limited.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath yes i thought about insertion sort. But the array could be longer, if say 1 to 1-million is present in the stream, in that case 1-million-1 would be the answer. but yes i agree sometimes i might don't have to read the entire stream.

Comment: "but yes i agree sometimes i might don't have to read the entire stream." - nobody said that. you *have to* read the whole stream. always.

Comment: @xtrmcode I agree, you always have to read the whole stream, unless you have constraints you didn't tell us about.

Comment: @karloy @ luchian no sorry I am wrong. I was thinking wrong. yes for any case you have to read the entire stream.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a method in case following two constraints are satisfied. This algorithm would scan the stream twice and need 256KB memory.

1. Each element is less than or equal to `0xFFFFFFFF`.
2. All elements in the stream are distinct.

Following shows this algorithm.

1. Allocate an array: `unsigned int bucket[2^16]`.
2. Scan this streaming data. If current data is `a`, then `bucket[a>>16]++`;
3. After scanning this stream, find the first bucket whose value is less than `2^16`.The first missing unsigned integer is in this bucket. Let the index of this bucket to be `k`, and the first remaining unsigned integer to be `n`. Then `k*(2^16) <= n < (k+1)*(2^16)`.
4. Reset value of all buckets to be zero.
5. Scan this streaming data again. If current data is `a` and `k*(2^16) <= a < (k+1)*(2^16)`, then `bucket[a&0xFFFF]++`.
6. After scanning this stream again, find the first bucket whose value is zero. Let the index of this bucket to be `h`.
7. This answer `n = k*(2^16) + h`.

   **Note:** The bucket[0] in the third step should be at most `2^16 - 1` rather than `2^16` because the set of unsigned integers doesn't include 0.

   ˊ