# Smallest positive integer not in a specific combination of two unsorted arrays

Tags: algorithm

### Classic problem

> Given an unsorted array `A` of integers, find the smallest positive integer which doesn't exist in `A`.
>
> [3, 2, 1, 6, 5] -> 4
> [2, 3, 4, 5] -> 1
> [1, 2, 3, 4] -> 5

In this classic problem you are given just one array, and you can find a lot of solutions and resources about this problem, including [stack**overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586858/find-the-smallest-integer-not-in-a-list), [Code Review@SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/179037/given-an-array-of-integers-return-the-smallest-positive-integer-not-in-it) and [geeksforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-smallest-positive-number-missing-from-an-unsorted-array/).

### Hard edition

In my problem you are given two arrays, `A` and `B`, both of length `N`. Construct an array `C` of length `N`, whose *smallest missing integer* is **maximum** possible. `C[i]` must be either `A[i]` or `B[i]`.

A = [1, 2, 4, 3],
B = [1, 3, 2, 3] =->
C = [1, 2, 4, 3] answer = 5

A = [4, 2, 1, 6, 5],
B = [3, 2, 1, 7, 7] =->
C = [3, 2, 1, 6, 5] answer = 4

A = [2, 3],
B = [4, 5] =->
C = [2, 5] answer = 1

How can we solve this problem with `O(N)` worst-case time and space complexity?

Assume that:

```
1<= N <= 100,000
1<= A[i], B[i] <= 100,000,000
```

Comment: why -1, please let me know? let me fix the issue..

Comment: Generally people don't like a post that only consists of a problem description. Personally I don't think anything is wrong with this particular post.

Comment: Effort is only required for homework, see [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: yes, you are right, im aware of that. but i already tried to solve this with classic way. should I send you pictures my papers?!

Comment: Info: This is known as the minimum excludant.

Comment: (are you sure that it's possible to solve it in O(n)?)

Comment: yeah, i am pretty sure. i failed to solve it despite of 1 hour of thinking.

Comment: Then how can you be so sure?

Comment: @user202729, because the requirements say so :) it is given in the problem statement itself.

Comment: In that case, you should link to the problem. Although not strictly required ([meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278771/how-to-deal-if-the-user-asks-for-code-in-online-programming-competition)), I think it's good practice. (just my opinion. I can't find any meta post, but then the answerers should feel that you aren't cheating)

Comment: can you please add the limitation of elements, i.e. ? <= a[i] <= ?

Comment: @user202729, I already entered the contest, so I am not cheating. I just want to know the solution. And this is the problem: https://app.codility.com/programmers/custom_challenge/germanium2018/

Comment: @user202729, but you have every right to be suspicious :))

Comment: @NourAlhadiMahmoud, I added the constraints. forgot to wright before, sorry.

Comment: This is a current challenge, which people can still join, and Codility does allow multiple trial for a challenge.

Comment: @m69 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258295/questions-from-active-contests?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you iterate over the arrays and build a graph, where each unique integer you encounter in A or B becomes a vertex, and each pair of integers A[i] and B[i] creates an edge between two vertices, then this graph will have at most 2×N vertices, so the space taken up by this graph is linear to N.

Then, for every edge in the graph, we will decide its direction, i.e. which of the two integers it connects will be used in array C. Finally, we will iterate over the arrays again, and for each pair of integers, we look at the corresponding edge in the graph to know which of the integers to use.

I believe the operations needed to decide the directions in the graph can all be done in linear time to N (correct me if I'm wrong), so the whole algorithm should have O(N) time and space complexity.

The rules for deciding the edge directions in the graph are as follows:

- Unconnected parts of the graph are each treated seperately.
- If a (sub-) graph has fewer edges than vertices (i.e. it has a tree-structure with no cycles), then the highest integer has to be sacrificed: point the edges away from that vertex, and propagate that direction over the rest of the vertices.
- If a (sub-) graph has more edges than vertices (i.e. it contains at least one cycle, which could be two vertices connected by multiple edges), then find any cycle, and give its edges the same direction (either clockwise or anti-clockwise); then propagate the direction to the other vertices.

While iterating over the arrays and looking up the corresponding edges in the graph, mark which integer you've already used when two vertices are multi-connected, so that the second time you use the other integer. After that, you can pick either one.

Example:

```
A = [1,6,2,9,7,2,5,3,4,10]
B = [5,8,3,2,9,7,1,2,8,3]
```

Graph:

```
1===5   6---8---4   9---2===3---10
                    |   |
                    --7--
```

We find the cycles [1>5>1] and [9>2>7>9], and the highest integer 8 in the non-cyclic sub-graph.

Directed graph:

```
1<=>5   6<--8-->4   9-->2<=>3-->10
                    ^   |
                    |-7<-
```

Result:

```
C = [1,6,2,2,9,7,5,3,4,10]
```

The first missing integer is 8, because we had to sacrifice it to save the 4 and the 6 in the [6,8,4] subgraph.

Comment: Only correct if all numbers are positive, for example it fails for `A = [-2], B = [1]`.

Comment: @user202729 Well, the title says "positive integer".

Comment: @user202729 The examples suggest that positive input is assumed, but I could be wrong. Anyway, it's easily fixed.

Comment: inputs are all positive, but thats not a big deal, as long as the algorithm work correct for positive integers.

Comment: Here is what I say. You have 10x more score than user202729, so it would be nicer to support a rising member. What is your opinion? Which one would you accept if you were me?

Comment: Not to mention that both of you guys are nice to new comers?

Answer (score 2):

This algorithm works in `O(n)` arithmetic operations on numbers in the number range `[0..n+2]`, plus the time for processing input.

---

- Replace all numbers not in range `[1..n]` with `n+2`. This will not change the result.
- Construct a graph with the nodes labeled `1, 2, 3, ..., n-1, n, n+2`, and for all `0 <= i < n`, there exists an edge between node `A[i]` and `B[i]` (assume 0-indexing array). So the graph has `n+1` nodes and `n` edges.

Now the problem is equivalent to finding a way to direct the edges such that the minimum vertex with in-degree 0 is maximum possible.

---

- Find the connected components in the graph.
- For each connected components with `v` vertices and `e` edges, `e >= v-1`:

  - If `e == v-1`, it's a tree. All ways to direct the edges will result in a vertex having in-degree 0, and it can be proven that for all vertex in the tree, there exists a way to direct the edges such that it's the only vertex having in-degree 0.

    Method:

    > Root the tree at that vertex, and then make every edges direct from the parent to the child.

    Of course, it's optimal to (greedily) choose the vertex having in-degree 0 to be the vertex with highest number.
  - If `e >= v`, there exists a circuit inside the connected component. Then, it's possible to direct the edges such that all vertices have nonzero in-degree.

    The proof (and method to construct the edge direction) is left to the reader.

Comment: It seems we posted the same (or at least very similar) answer at exactly the same time :-)

Comment: @m69 and user202729, I upvoted both of you, but don't know which one I should accept. btw do both of these algorithms work in O(N), or are they O(A[i])?

Comment: @EzizDurdyyev They are both O(N); it's basically the same idea. And we literally posted within seconds of each other, so I don't know what to tell you. In the end, accepting is about the answer "which you found most helpful", so that's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code snippet, I have written in Java 8

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;


public class Run {
    private int solution(int[] A) {

        List<Integer> positiveIntegerList = Arrays.stream(A).distinct().filter(e -> e > 0).boxed().sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        final int i = 1;

        if (!positiveIntegerList.isEmpty()) {
            final int missingMax = positiveIntegerList.get(positiveIntegerList.size() - i) + i;
            List<Integer> range = IntStream.rangeClosed(i, positiveIntegerList.get(positiveIntegerList.size() - i))
                    .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

            AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();
            return range.stream().filter(e -> !e.equals(positiveIntegerList.get(index.getAndIncrement()))).findFirst().
                    orElse(missingMax);
        } else {
            return i;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Run run = new Run();
        int[] intArray = new int[]{1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2};
        System.out.println(run.solution(intArray));
    }
}
```

Comment: you should add some explanation to your solution.

Comment: You would notice this does not solve any problem about *two* arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried my way of solving this problem in Python3. Suggestions and feedback are welcome. Thanks.

1. Remove negative values from the list
2. Insert 0 to the list
3. Sort and remove duplicates from the list using sorted and set function
4. Create index, value using enumerator.
5. Compare index and value starting from (0, 0). If index and value doesn't match, then the next value is the smallest positive number.

--

```
from typing import List

class Solution:
    def firstMissingPositive(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        #Remove all the negative values from the list
        positive_list = [i for i in nums if i > 0]

        #Appending Zero to list. In case of no postive values in the list.
        positive_list.append(0)

        #Sort and remove duplicates from the list using Sorted and set function
        sorted_postive_list = sorted(set(positive_list))

        #starting with (index, value) --> (0,0), Compare index and value, and if they don't match then next value should be the smallest positive number
        return next((a for a, b in enumerate(sorted_postive_list, sorted_postive_list[0]) if a != b), sorted_postive_list[-1]+1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num = [1,2,3,0]
    a = Solution()
    print(a.firstMissingPositive(num))
```

Comment: This does not solve any problem about *two* arrays. For the related classic problem, the solution looks slow and [undocumented](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring) but straight.