Smallest Integer Problem Code Performance
I am starting Python and I came across this practice test where I have to find the smallest positive integer that does not occur in a list.
Examples:

arr = [8, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5] # output: 6
arr = [-3, 1, 1, -7, 5, 3] # output: 2
arr = [-11, -1, 3] # output: 1

Here's my solution:
def solution(A):
    val = 1
    while True:
        try:
            idx = A.index(val)
            val += 1
        except ValueError:
            break
    return val


According to my results, I only got 1 out of the 4 performance tests. Could someone help me understand why?

if val not in A: would be better than the try/except block.

Have you analyzed the time complexity of your solution/do you know what big-O is? Are you more interested in knowing why your solution isn’t fast enough, or in coming up with alternatives? Does the problem have any more constraints on the input or time/space you should target? There’s a well-known fancy solution to this, but also many more generic approaches that are basically good enough (O(n) time and O(n) space).

@Ry- What are the complexities of the fancy one?

@nocomment: O(1) space and O(n) time if mutating the input is allowed, or O(1) space and O(n log n) time if not are the “interesting” ones I’m aware of. Both covered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586858/find-the-smallest-integer-not-in-a-list

@Ry- Where there is the O(1) space and O(n log n) time one covered?

@nocomment: Egon’s answer

The problem is that A.index(val) sequentially searches the list until it finds val (or not), implicitly creating another while loop within your while loop, giving O(n²) running time.
An alternative approach is to convert your list of integers to a set before further processing.
def solution(A):
    S = set(A)
    val = 1
    while True:
        if val not in S:
            return val
        val += 1

The set class is implementing using a hash table, which allows membership tests (in or not in) to be performed very quickly, without having to loop through all of the values in the set.

You need to analyze time complexity to understand the bottle neck.
Suppose K is the smallest integer you are looking for, and N is the length of your list.
Then your code has complexity O(K*N), because for each iteration over K you are searching the list which takes O(N).
Now let's think about the best conceivable runtime (BCR). To find the integer you are inevitable (with a random list) need to iterate through the whole list, which is O(N). All the other parts might be dropped probably depending on the implementation. So our BCR = O(N). Most probably you need to target this time complexity to have all performance tests to pass.
Now to the solution. I don't think it's optimal, but it will definitely improve your version. You can convert list to the hashset. The search operation in hashset is O(1), so your solution will become O(K+N). The downside is that your space complexity will increase from O(1) to O(N)
def solution(A):
    B = set(A)
    val = 1
    while True:
        if val in B:
            val += 1
        else:
            break
    return val


while val in B: val += 1

The question is "why is this solution bad."
The answer is A.index(val) has to iterate through the list in order to find the position of val. It has to do this for each and every int, until you get an answer. This of course makes this an O(n^2) worst case solution. The correct answer will be O(n).
This is actually a pretty common problem when working with lists. If you are iterating a loop, and within that loop you use a list member that iterates over the list, then you have a double loop, even though it doesn't look like it.

If you get correct answers with time fails, that is a strong indicator to look at time complexity.

"The correct answer will be O(n)" - The answer to what question?

That's referring to the underlying assignment, not to the SO question which was just to identify the problem in the bad solution.

Still unclear. That sounds like you think the assignment asks what is the optimal time complexity. But as far as I can tell, it asks for code. Also, I see no reason to believe that O(n log n) isn't acceptable.

So what? Theirs isn't O(n log n) but O(n^2). Huge difference.

@KlimentMerzlyakov's solution improves the average time complexity from O(n ^ 2) to O(n) at the cost of space having to store all the numbers in a set.
You can improve the space overhead while keeping the time complexity at O(n) by storing each positive integer as a set bit in a binary number instead. Then invert the number so the lowest set bit would be at the the smallest positive integer. You can get the lowest set bit with the algorithm from this answer.
As @Ry- pointed out in the comment, however, since integers are immutable in Python and have to be copied for each operation, storing the bits as an integer would result in a time complexity of O(n ^ 2). Instead, you can store the bits in a bytearray to perform operations in-place, and then iteratively find the index of the lowest byte with an unset bit to calculate the position of the lowest unset bit, so that each additional number would only cost 1 bit of space overhead while the overall time complexity remains at O(n):
def solution(A):
    size = len(A)
    b = bytearray((size >> 3) + 1)
    for i in A:
        if 0 < i <= size:
            i -= 1
            b[i >> 3] |= 1 << (i & 7)
    for i, byte in enumerate(b):
        if byte != 255:
            break
    byte = ~byte
    return (i << 3) + (byte & -byte).bit_length()

so that:
for arr in (
    list(range(1000)) + list(range(1001, 2000)),
    [8, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5],
    [-3, 1, 1, -7, 5, 3],
    [-11, -1, 3]
):
    print(solution(arr))

outputs:
1000
6
2
1

Demo here

I think the only way this could be considered not a duplicate would be because of the request for why the asker’s original solution isn’t efficient, and your answer doesn’t address that (in good company, which is why I closed it). Did you reopen it just to get an answer in?

Also, this would be O(max value) instead of O(length) if it operated in place (not hard to fix), but ints are immutable so it’s actually O(n^2).

@Ry- You're right that my solution was of O(max value) in space complexity, which I've now fixed with a size guard. Note that ints of the prior iterations are automatically garbage collected so it won't cost O(n ^ 2).

It won’t cost O(n^2) space, but copying the prior iterations takes a total of O(n^2) time.

Can you show such a case, i.e., an input list for which the loop ends with byte equaling 255? Yes, my bit version was for simplicity. For speed, you could use for byte in b: and then i = b.find(byte) after the loop. Using enumerate is wasteful if you're throwing away all but one index. But your second loop is much faster than the first anyway. Removing the i -= 1 from the first might have more impact.

While not the fastest solution, sorting is an option that will run in O(1) memory, O(n log n) time, assuming you can do it in-place. This may make it more practically viable than using a set for very large inputs.
def min_pos_int(arr):
    arr.sort()
    if arr[0] > 1: return 1
    for i in range(len(arr) - 1):
        if arr[i] >= 1 and arr[i + 1] > arr[i] + 1:
            return arr[i] + 1
        elif arr[i] < 1 and arr[i + 1] > 1:
            return 1
    else:
        return max(1, arr[-1] + 1)

If you implement the sort yourself, you can optimize quite a bit further. For example, in a qsort, you can avoid recursing into the negative partitions, and will know the beginning of the positive side immediately.

In this vein, a quickselect-like approach or using the array as a set (like this answer) will give O(n) time.

@nocomment. Good call on all counts. Fixed. This was written on mobile, so not tested as it should have been

Meh, I've been solely on mobile for over a year, that's not a problem. I resubmitted at https://leetcode.com/problems/first-missing-positive/description/ now, now it failed on input [-5]. Btw, my favorite finish after sorting: Attempt This Online! (And that site is where I do most coding/testing, very mobile-friendly and up-to-date Python version.)

@nocomment. Fixed the new test case.

Submitted again, now failed [-1,-2,-60,40,43] (returned 41). Another I like: Attempt This Online! (Could be optimized with elif a > i: break, but that could also make it slower.)

Added another fix :)

And now LeetCode accepts it. But I'd say it has become quite complicated :-P ... Btw Python's (at least CPython's) list.sort isn't O(1) memory but O(n) memory.

@nocomment. list.sort should be in-place. sorted(list) is not.

It's in-place only in the sense that the result ends up in the same list. Not in-place in the sense of not allocating extra memory. To do its job, it does temporarily allocate additional memory. Up to four bytes per element.

@nocomment. Docs don't seem to agree with you (assuming you're not using a key of course) This method modifies the sequence in place for economy of space when sorting a large sequence. Straight from https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort

That does agree with me. Four bytes per element is still less than twelve. You can also read its source code or Tim's listsort.txt. Quote: "timsort can require a temp array containing as many as N//2 pointers".
